# iOS Safari ignores HTML 'maxlength' attribute

Tags: ios, css, iphone, jsp

i am using below line of code to restrict the user but not working for iphone
    maxlength ="4";

```
<input type="number" name="securitycode"  id="securityCode" maxlength="4" />
```

Is there any way to enforce this on iOS?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue. One work around is to use jQuery to restrict this.

```
$('input[name="securitycode"]').keypress(function() {
    if (this.value.length >= 4) {
        return false;
    }
});
```